# Raspberry Pi - HTML forms not submitting

Tags: html, forms, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi that is effectively being used as a kiosk display. It auto starts Chromium and goes to a webpage which displays some data. There is a form on this page and a barcode reader attached to the Pi which, when a barcode is scanned dumps the contents of the barcode into the textbox and simulates a carriage return (enter).

This works in console on the Pi and on other machines which have no problem with the webpage however, on the Pi it will generally dump the contents of the barcode and won't submit the form - if you attach the keyboard and hit enter nothing happens; change the focus onto the button and hit enter - nothing happens!

[image: The form on the Pi]

My HTML code for the form:

```html
<table class="footer">
  <tr class='grey'>
    <td>
      <?php echo date( "d/m/Y - H:i:s", time()); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form action='board_update.php' id="id" method='post'><input type='text' name='id' autofocus='autofocus'/><input type="submit " value="Submit " /></form></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The page has a meta tag which causes it to refresh at 5 minute intervals (which it does).

I'm wondering what the problem is? The form or the Pi?

Comment: Can't know for sure, but probably has something to do with the extra quote at the end here: `<form action='board_update.php' id="id" method='post' ">` Run your HTML through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/), fix the errors and try again.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using the 'pi' tag. Also, if the RPi is the problem (which it almost definitely isn't) then you should be asking on the raspberry pi Q&A stackexchange site.

Comment: @Juhana - Sorry, didn't see that but I'm not sure why it works sometimes but not others - it's very inconsistent.

Comment: Tobasta - apologies, I've changed the tag.

Comment: I've removed that extra quote @Juhana but it hasn't made any difference and the validator isn't displaying any errors.

Comment: Looks like you also have `<input type="submit "` -> there's an extra space there between the t and the ". See if deleting that makes a difference.

Comment: Changed but no success unfortunately. Pi is misbehaving in other regards - I think it's knackered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that after much troubleshooting and replicating the setup on another Pi, that it is indeed the Raspberry Pi at fault. Something is either wrong with the OS or hardware but I've replaced the entire set up and so far, so good.